# mat-sort ascending with null values to last

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have a mat-sort-header with a date .I want to sort the table data with ascending based on dates
, but want the null dates displayed last. The problem is that when im sorting by asccending , the null dates are shown first.

```html
    <table  mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="list-table list-table"
     matSort matSortActive="due_date" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear>   
     
     <ng-container matColumnDef="due_date">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{ "DUE DATE" | translate }}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <span *ngIf="element?.due_date!==null">{{ element.due_date | dateTranslation }}</span>
          <span *ngIf="element?.due_date==null">{{'NO DUE DATE'|translate}}</span>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
```

What are the options to display null values to last when ordered by ascending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was, making a custom sort and hooking to ngAfterViewInit:

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dataSource.sortData = (data, sort: MatSort) => {
  let sortedData = [];
  sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
    const direction = this.getSortingOrder(sort.direction, a, b);
    if (!direction[0][sort.active] || !direction[1][sort.active]) {
      return sort.direction === "asc" ? 0 : -1;
    } else {
      return direction[0][sort.active]
        .toString()
        .localeCompare(direction[1][sort.active]);
    }
  });
  return sortedData;
   };
 }


  getSortingOrder = (order, a, b) => {
    const sorted = order === "asc" ? [a, b] : [b, a];
    return sorted;
  }
```

This will push the null values to last when sorted by ascending

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, which was "ignoring the null values when one clicks on the sort button, so that they are always printed at the end of the table".
I solved the problem this way:

- overhiding the sortingDataAccessor method of the MatTableDataSource
- checking the item protery value
- if the value is null, then checking the sort order
- according to sort order: returning a (possible) highest / lowest value so that the lines with null values are always at the end of the table (in your case, you would invert the returned values).

Here is a sample of code:

```
this.rankingData = new MatTableDataSource();
this.rankingData.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
    if(null == item[property]) {
      if("desc" == this.sort.direction) return '\u0000'+'\u0000'+'\u0000';
    return '\uFFFF'+'\uFFFF'+'\uFFFF';
  }
  return item[property];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Short solution! You can add an unreal big number if value is null, so it definitely put this item to the bottom

```
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
  return item[property] || 9999999999999;
};
```